# Macro to replace Method with specific Argument count

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a 'calculate' method with two different declarations:

```
int calculate(int parmA);
int calculate(int parmA, int parmB, int parmC);
```

I want to replace only calculate(int parmA) with a call to 'calculateNew':

```
int calculateNew(int parmA);
```

I have tried using define in two different ways:

```
#define calculate calculateNew
#define calculate(parmA) calculateNew(parmA)
```

When I do this I get compiler errors in other parts of the code due to different number of arguments:

```
macro "calculate" passed 2 arguments, but takes just one
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I tell the preprocessor to replace only if there is one argument? Can I even do that?

NOTE: I realize that this might not be the best approach to this problem, but it is required to be made this way.

Comment: Macro is the wrong tool for the job. Use the refactoring function in your favorite IDE.

Comment: Do you control any of the overloads? I mean, is renaming one of them (or pushing it into a namespace) an option?

Comment: @remyabel how can you just make a comment such as that without knowing the context? refactoring is certainly NOT the tool for the job. Macros might not be the way to do it, but I need to be able to define different behaviours upon certain conditions, having 2 different functions, and one of those functions being executed in place of the other when those conditions are met.

Comment: *"how can you just make a comment such as that without knowing the context?"*  **Only you** can explain the context for this problem.  It's a valid comment to what you have described.

Comment: @Angew Yes, I though about renaming and I can do that, but I would rather have a good solution, than a workaround because I can't do it in another way.

Comment: @DrewDormann I already thought of that, maybe I can't achieve this through macros. I can use inheritance and overload the methods, but I was looking for a simpler solution. If there is none, I will go the inheritance way...

Comment: Macros are just textual substitutions. When I saw `calculateNew`, from context I assumed that you were trying to *textually substitute* an old function with a new function. It is much more worth your time (and for future maintainers) to refactor instead of using macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account the comments and suggested answers, I actually made some changes to achieve what I needed, since Macros aren't suitable for the problem as it was.

Even though I don't really like the solution, it gets the job done, and I will take some time later on to come up with a more robust solution.

I made some refactoring, replacing the two declarations

```
int calculate(int parmA);
int calculate(int parmA, int parmB, int parmC);
```

with

```
int calculateSimple(int parmA);
int calculateComplex(int parmA, int parmB, int parmC);
```

This way I can easily replace the call with a macro

```
#define calculateSimple calculateNew
```

without any errors, and everything working as expected.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Still quite messy as everyone reading your code might not realize that in fact you always call a different function than written in the code. When you already renamed the two functions why don't you just replace `calculateSimple` with `calculateNew` right in the code? Makes it more clear and you get rid of that macro.

Comment: @a_guest the goal is to be able to emulate a specific behaviour, so when I define a certain variable the calls to that function are replaced with a new one. this is not the default behaviour nor I want the calculateNew to always be executed. I just want a set of functions to be replaced when I need to perform some tests that emulate behaviour that otherwise would be dependant of outside data. this way those functions can generate the data I need to make tests.

Answer (score 1):

I take it from your comments that you want to call one or the other based on some property known at preprocessor time. If you can rename the original overload, youcan make an inline trampoline. Rename your original single-argument overload to `originalCalculate` and then add this:

```
inline int calculate(int parmA)
{
#if new_should_be_used()
  calculateNew(parmA);
#else
  originalCalculate(parmA);
#endif
}
```

If you need different behaviour in different compilation units, just replace `inline` with `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring is definitely the way to go because otherwise your code will end up in a mess and will be harder to maintain.
But if you actually want a "workaround" (because that's what everything else is) why don't you overload `calculateNew` with 3 arguments and just call the initial version in the overloaded one:

```
int calculateNew (int a) { whatever };
int calculateNew (int a, int b, int c) { return calculate(a, b, c); };
```

Then you can use find & replace of your IDE to replace `calculate` with `calculateNew`.